# What is the most real-time method of determining SPI?

Tags: remote-sensing

For drought monitoring related to vegetation, I need to calculate Standardized Percipitation INdex for a given area. Where can I find the most real-time percipitation data to do this? The best I've found is CHIRPS data, which has a latency of one month. Is there any freely available data that is more up-to-date?

Comment: ERA5 data should be available with a 5 days gap to real time (https://www.ecmwf.int/en/forecasts/datasets/reanalysis-datasets/era5). However, using SPI you are still working on monthly deviation from long term average, therefore, I don't really see the benefit of using data updated for instance 5-days instead of 30-days to real time.

Answer (score 1):

There are more up-to-date datasets that are available after registration and acceptance of the respective data usage licences.

E.g. two satellite-derived products

- GSMaP https://sharaku.eorc.jaxa.jp/GSMaP/
- TRMM 3B42RT https://mirador.gsfc.nasa.gov/

For a more comprehensive overview, including evaluation against rain gauge data, see Beck et al. 2017.

Beck, H.E., Vergopolan, N., Pan, M., Levizzani, V., van Dijk, A.I., Weedon, G.P., Brocca, L., Pappenberger, F., Huffman, G.J. and Wood, E.F., 2017. Global-scale evaluation of 22 precipitation datasets using gauge observations and hydrological modelling. Hydrology and Earth System Sciences, 21(12), pp.6201-6217.